# Redirect whit SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

i have a problem with redirect page after the user click on ok button in sweet alert. i don't understand where i have to insert the code and which code. i would like that when the user press ok, after the success on form, is redirected to... example "google.com".

I tried to use the solutions on the site, but they did not work or I was wrong to insert them
Thanks to all for help

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
   if(response.length == 0) {
    //reCaptcha not verified
    alert("Verifica di non essere un robot!");
    return false;
   } else {
    //reCaptch verified
    $.blockUI({
     message: '<p><img src="img/Eclipse-1s-134px.svg" alt="">Ci siamo...non uscire</p>'
    });
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'mailer.php',
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
     xhr: function () {
      //upload Progress
      var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (xhr.upload) {
       xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
        var percent = 0;
        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
        var total = event.total;
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
         percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
        }
        //update progressbar
        $('.progress-bar').animate({
         width: percent + '%'
        }, {
         duration: 100
        });
       }, true);
      }
      return xhr;
     },
     success: function (response) {
      if (response.success) {
         Swal.fire(
           'Perfetto!',
           'Il tuo locale è registrato!',
           'success'
         );
       $('form').trigger("reset");
       $('.progress-bar').animate({
        width: '10%'
       }, {
        duration: 1000
       });
      
      } else {
       alert(response.message);
      }
     },
     error: function (response) {
           Swal.fire({
       icon: 'error',
       title: 'Oops...',
       text: 'Qualcosa è andato storto!',
       footer: '<a href>Riprovaci!</a>'
      });
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be placed before the success code, something like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
        $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if(response.length == 0) {
                //reCaptcha not verified
                alert("Verifica di non essere un robot!");
                return false;
            } else {
                //reCaptch verified
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<p><img src="img/Eclipse-1s-134px.svg" alt="">Ci siamo...non uscire</p>'
                });
                var formData = new FormData(this);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'mailer.php',
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    xhr: function () {
                        //upload Progress
                        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if (xhr.upload) {
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
                                var percent = 0;
                                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                                var total = event.total;
                                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                                }
                                //update progressbar
                                $('.progress-bar').animate({
                                    width: percent + '%'
                                }, {
                                    duration: 100
                                });
                            }, true);
                        }
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                                Swal.fire(
                                   'Perfetto!',
                                   'Il tuo locale è registrato!',
                                   'success'
                                 );
                            $('form').trigger("reset");
                            $('.progress-bar').animate({
                                width: '10%'
                            }, {
                                duration: 1000
                            });

                            window.location.href = 'www.yourpage.com';

                        } else {
                            alert(response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                                        Swal.fire({
                         icon: 'error',
                         title: 'Oops...',
                         text: 'Qualcosa è andato storto!',
                         footer: '<a href>Riprovaci!</a>'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```